# .Net Reg Ex exact match

Tags: .net, regex

RegEx makes my head hurt, can anyone solve this for me?

In c# I'm calling the following and expecting true, I must admit I'm very week at regex.

Also a brief explanation on the implications of the impact of ( ) and the \ before the &.

```
var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(
     "from=20100101&to=20121231",
     "^(from=)([0-9]{6})\\&to=([0-9]{6})$"
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return true

```
var isValid = Regex.IsMatch("from=20100101&to=20121231",@"^from=[0-9]{8}&to=[0-9]{8}$");
```

The `\` is used to escape an otherwise special character. So is treated at its literal value and not for its meaning in the Regular Expression Language. For example `\.` means match a point while a `.` by itself is a wildcard and means "Matches any single character except \n."

The `(subexpression)` is called grouping and captures everything matched with the inside subexpression and assigns it a zero-based ordinal number. This match could be referenced with the ordinal number assigned using this syntax `\0`
The argument is broad and has numerous variations.
You could start from this [reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.90%29)

Note. I have corrected your pattern removing the grouping, the \& (ampersand is not a special char) and extending the number matching to 8 digits 
(if you have dates composed of only 6 digits then you could set {6,8} meaning min 6, max 8 digits)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the fix.  I can't seem to mark multiple replies as the answer.

Comment: You are free to give your check to the best one and change your mind at will

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^from=(\d{8})&to=(\d{8})$
```

Answer (score 1):

You have asked for 6 consecutive digits with the {6}.  However, you are really looking for 8, yyyymmdd.